Were there mistakes in converting Dijkstra's Algol-60 compiler to Pascal?
In his paper The Dijkstra–Zonneveld ALGOL 60 compiler for the Electrologica X1 F.E.J. Kruseman Aretz presents his attempt at reproducing the functionality of the original compiler, written in the Electrologica X1 assembly language, in a Pascal program. Given that the X1 word size was 27 bit, and, unlike contemporary computers, its integer arithmetic was 1's complement, some transcription mistakes would not be out of the question. Were there any?

The Pascal transcription of the assembly language code attempts to maintain an invariant: all Pascal variables that represent X1 words, are trimmed to 27 bit. However, there is at least one mistake/typo: in calculating the "storage function" for arrays, specifically, the base address of the array, corresponding to the (real or imaginary) array element indexed by all zeros (page 141 of the PDF), there is
    1415 arrc:= arrc - (arrd * store[tlsc-1]) mod d26;

This violates the invariant in case of negative array bounds. arrc may become a negative 32-bit integer, resulting in miscalculated storage functions and potential memory corruptions during program execution. The correct code must be
    1415 arrc:= (arrc - arrd * store[tlsc-1]) mod d26;

Let's first consider the basic case, a single-dimensional array with the usual lower bound of 1. For
        _b_e_g_i_n
            _r_e_a_l _a_r_r_a_y a[1:10];
            print(a[10]);
        _e_n_d

the compiler produces (as disassembled by a script by @dirkt, slightly edited for clarity)
  023640:       0140  START
  023641: 0422023651    2B 023651 A address of the "storage function"
  023642:        017  TRAS          take real address static
  023643: 0422023655    2B 023655 A address of constant 10
  023644:        042  TIRS          take integer result static
  023645:        070  IND           index
  023646:        072  TAR           take result
  023647:       0147  print
  023650:       0141  STOP
  023651:       0212                array location
  023652:       0210                (hypothetical) address of a[0]
  023653:         02                2 words per element for reals
  023654: 0777777753                -20 (total words) in 1's complement
  023655:        012                10

Here the address of a[0] is indeed two words below the actual start of the memory for the array. So far so good.
(For arrays with zero lower bound, as expected, the address of a[0] matches the array location.)
Now, for brevity, without the print statement, for an array with a negative lower bound:
        _b_e_g_i_n
            _i_n_t_e_g_e_r _a_r_r_a_y a[-1:1];
        _e_n_d

we get
  023640:       0140  START
  023641:       0141  STOP
  023642:       0212                   array base
  023643: 0400000212                   must be 213
  023644:         01                   1 word per element for integers
  023645: 0777777774                   -3 in 1's complement

Perhaps the most significant bit means something, like a correction by one, you say? Let's try

        _b_e_g_i_n
            _i_n_t_e_g_e_r _a_r_r_a_y a[-1:1,-1:1];
        _e_n_d

For the above, we get
  023640:       0140  START
  023641:       0141  STOP
  023642:       0212                  array base
  023643:       0215                  must be 4 greater than the base
  023644:         01                  words per element
  023645:         03                  words per dimension
  023646: 0777777766                  -9 in 1's complement

Indeed, for an array [-1:1,-1:1] the element [0,0] is right in the middle of the 9 elements of the array, which address would be 4 greater than that of the first element, not 3 (215 minus 212). The bug is apparent.
With the fix, the addresses of the zero-indexed element become correct. The upper bit may still appear in some cases, but it does not hurt.

And you know this how !!! ? ||  :-) :-) :-) (Inquiring minds want to know).

@RussellMcMahon Please see update.

@RussellMcMahon They're resurrecting the Algol compiler, makes sense they'd run into bugs like this.

Another problem was found by the cppcheck tool analyzing the result of conversion of the Pascal program to C. Going back to the Pascal source, we can see
      {actual parameter separator:}
      if store[tlsc-1] mod d8 = 87{,}
      then if aflag = 0
           then if (store[tlsc-2] = rlsc)
                   and (fflag = 0) and (jflag = 0) and (nflag = 1)   <----!!!
                then begin if nid > nlscop
                       then begin if (pflag = 1) and (fflag = 0)     <----!!!
                              then {non-formal procedure:}
                                   test_first_occurrence;

Here the condition fflag = 0 is tested twice in nested if conditions, redundantly. Clearly one of the tests is a mistake.
Indeed, as presented, the compiler generates inefficient object code.
According to Dijkstra's description of the compiler,  whenever there is a direct passing of a formal parameter in a subroutine as an actual parameter to another, like
b̲e̲g̲i̲n̲
    p̲r̲o̲c̲e̲d̲u̲r̲e̲ t(i); r̲e̲a̲l̲ i; print(i);
    p̲r̲o̲c̲e̲d̲u̲r̲e̲ p(i); r̲e̲a̲l̲ i; t(i);
    p(3.14159); NLCR
e̲n̲d̲

(NB t(i) in the procedure p, where i is a formal parameter), the descriptor of the actual parameter was intended to have a special type designator.

The two bits ... specify ... whether the actual parameter as it stands in the procedure statement is already formal (the "handing on" of a formal parameter).

(https://github.com/sergev/x1-algol-compiler/blob/main/doc/mr35.pdf page 17 of the PDF).
However, for the program above the following object code is produced:
023600   1 0000000140  START
023601   1 0522023610    GOTO 023610 A     skipping procedure t
023602   1 0422000001    2B 000001 A       start of t; nesting level 1
023603   1 0000000131  SCC                 prepare frame
023604   1 0122000241    2S 000241 A       ID of the 1st formal parameter
023605   1 0000000043  TFR                 take its value
023606   1 0000000147  print               
023607   1 0000000014  RET                 return from t
023610   1 0522023624    GOTO 023624 A     skipping procedure p
023611   1 0422000001    2B 000001 A       start of p, nesting level 1
023612   1 0000000131  SCC
023613   1 0422023602    2B 023602 A       address of t
023614   1 0522023621    GOTO 023621 A     skip the thunk and the param list
023615   1 0122000241    2S 000241 A       ID of the 1st formal parameter
023616   1 0000000043  TFR                 take its value
023617   1 0000000015  EIS                 end of thunk (implicit subroutine)
023620   1 0004023615    0A 023615 B       address of the thunk, with a flag
023621   1 0022000001    2A 000001 A       parameter count
023622   1 0000000011  ETMP                call the subroutine (t)
023623   1 0000000014  RET                 return from p
023624   1 0422023611    2B 023611 A       address of p
023625   1 0522023627    GOTO 023627 A     skip parameter block
023626   1 0000023633    0A 023633         address of the constant
023627   1 0022000001    2A 000001 A       parameter count
023630   1 0000000011  ETMP                call the subroutine (p)
023631   1 0000000151  NLCR                print newline
023632   1 0000000141  STOP
023633   1 0311037476  
023634   1 0003344002  

Here we can see that to pass the formal parameter a from p to t, a trivial thunk (words 23615-23617) is used. That uses more execution time and stack space than necessary.
With a fix, removing the first of the two fflag = 0 checks, the object code for the call of t from p becomes
023613   1 0422023602    2B 023602 A
023614   1 0522023616    GOTO 023616 A
023615   1 0020600005  Y 2A 000005   P     the intended descriptor of `a` 
023616   1 0022000001    2A 000001 A
023617   1 0000000011  ETMP

The "two bits" Dijkstra talks about, are the two upper bits in the 6 digit of the word 23615.
This allows the runtime to shortcut the access to formal parameters passed down unmodified. The corrected compiler passes all our tests and it is able to produce a more efficient code for Man or boy test, using 15% less stack.
It is not 100% clear, though, if that is a transcription error or a genuine regression; the assembly code seemingly contains a combined check for fflag = 0 and jflag = 0, but I could not find what could have corresponded to the nested check for fflag = 0. We would only know for sure after a definitive test simulating the machine code of the compiler.
